# Sentiment Analysis Tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to understand sentiment analysis and how to apply it using any language (R, Python etc). I would like to know if there is a good place on internet for tutorial that I can follow. I googled, but I wasn't very much satisfied because they were not tutorials but more of theory. I want theory and practical examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stanford NLP course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp) covers Sentiment Analysis in [week 3](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/preview):
- [What is Sentiment Analysis?](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/31)
- [Sentiment Analysis: A baseline algorithm](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/145)
- [Sentiment Lexicons](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/35)
- [Learning Sentiment Lexicons](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/144)
- [Other Sentiment Tasks](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/33)

For coding tutorials see:

- [Stream Hacker's NLP tutorials](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/)
- [Basic Sentiment Analysis with Python](http://fjavieralba.com/basic-sentiment-analysis-with-python.html)
- [Andy Bromberg's Sentiment Analysis tutorials](http://andybromberg.com/sentiment-analysis-python/)
- [Laurent Luce's Sentiment Analysis tutorials](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/)

These are really basic, so their performance will not be great in all cases.

Comment: Yeah, the tutorials by StramHacker are the best out there for NLP with Python.

Comment: The top result on Google for [sentiment analysis with python] links to it, but somehow it itself is not up there.  In any case I think adding [with python] drastically shifts the Google results towards practical coding tutorials, my guess is that that exact query formulation simply did not occur to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

The [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) is by far the best tutorial on basic NLP I have seen(in Python).

The Coursera [course](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp) on NLP is also fairly good. It takes off from the basics and takes the student to a novice level.

Answer (score 2):

As *Dawny* said i would suggest [NLTK Book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) too. And in R language ['tm'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) library is pretty useful. So try [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html) for more related text mining stuff with R. [r-blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/text-mining/) also worth of consider.
good luck.